# How do I stop ext-js from adding limit=25 to my JSON query?

Tags: javascript, extjs

The following code is working. The problem is the request is being sent with &_dc=1299207914646&limit=25 appended to every request sent to the server. Nothing I can do changes the limit=25. Ideally I want no additional parameters sent to the server. I would make do however with being able to set the limit to 10000 or something. I AM able to add other parameters but nothing I do removes the limit=25. I would also like to get rid of the &_dc parameter although I don't know why it has been added it is not causing a problem.

Any ideas?

note: some weird problem with code formatting below?

Thanks

```
    Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.panel.*'
]);
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.regModel('Image_', { // window.Image is protected in ie6 !!!
        fields: ['id', 'key', 'value']
    });    

var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        model: 'Image_',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        model: 'Image_',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            autoload: 'false',
            url: '/couchdb/test/_design/blah/_view/by_surname2?startkey=%22r%22&endkey=%22r\u9999%22',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
               root: 'rows'
                    }
        }
    });
    store.load();




    var listView = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        width:425,
        height:250,
        collapsible:true,
        title:'Simple ListView <i>(0 items selected)</i>',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

        store: store,
        multiSelect: true,
        viewConfig: {
            emptyText: 'No images to display'
        },


        headers: [{
            text: 'File',
            flex: 50,
            dataIndex: 'value'
        },{
            text: 'Last Modified',
            flex: 35, 
            dataIndex: 'key'
        },{
            text: 'Size',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            flex: 15,
            cls: 'listview-filesize'
        }]
    });

    // little bit of feedback
    listView.on('selectionchange', function(view, nodes){
        var l = nodes.length;
        var s = l != 1 ? 's' : '';
        listView.setTitle('Simple ListView <i>('+l+' item'+s+' selected)</i>');
    });
});
```

Comment: just set `limitParam: undefined` on your proxy

Answer (score 9):

In your Proxy, set

```
limitParam: undefined,
pageParam: undefined,
startParam: undefined,
noCache: false,
```

Comment: is there a global config for limitParam, startParam & pageParam for store, which we can override?

Answer (score 4):

You can modify your store limit when you load the store.

```
store.load({params:{limit:50}});
```

In this case, I am asking to set the limit to 50.
_dc=1299207914646 is unique cache-buster param added to GET requests. If you don't want to have them in the url, you can disable them by setting **disableCaching** parameter to false.

But I would recommend you to set the method of you store to POST and pass the parameters using POST rather than GET method. That way you can have clean URLs and also hide the data being sent.

Comment: +1 for disableCaching. -1 for suggesting a POST. You should only use a POST when you are modifying data on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `getParams` method of the [`Ext.data.proxy.Server`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Server.html#Ext-data-proxy-Server).

For example, in my project I added custom boolean parameter `embeddedParams` and if I dont want to add ExtJS parameters to a request I set it to `false` in a store proxy:

```
/**
 * Added embeddedParams option
 */
Ext.define('Ext.lib.overrides.ServerProxy', {
    override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Server',

    /**
     * Add or not pagination, grouping, sorting and filtering parameters to the request. Defaults to true.
     */
    embeddedParams: true,

    /**
     * @private
     * Copy any sorters, filters etc into the params so they can be sent over the wire
     */
    getParams: function (operation) {
        var me = this,
            params = {},
            isDef = Ext.isDefined,
            groupers = operation.groupers,
            sorters = operation.sorters,
            filters = operation.filters,
            page = operation.page,
            start = operation.start,
            limit = operation.limit,
            simpleSortMode = me.simpleSortMode,
            simpleGroupMode = me.simpleGroupMode,
            pageParam = me.pageParam,
            startParam = me.startParam,
            limitParam = me.limitParam,
            groupParam = me.groupParam,
            groupDirectionParam = me.groupDirectionParam,
            sortParam = me.sortParam,
            filterParam = me.filterParam,
            directionParam = me.directionParam,
            hasGroups, index;

        if (me.embeddedParams && pageParam && isDef(page)) {
            params[pageParam] = page;
        }

        if (me.embeddedParams && startParam && isDef(start)) {
            params[startParam] = start;
        }

        if (me.embeddedParams && limitParam && isDef(limit)) {
            params[limitParam] = limit;
        }

        hasGroups = me.embeddedParams && groupParam && groupers && groupers.length > 0;
        if (hasGroups) {
            // Grouper is a subclass of sorter, so we can just use the sorter method
            if (simpleGroupMode) {
                params[groupParam] = groupers[0].property;
                params[groupDirectionParam] = groupers[0].direction || 'ASC';
            } else {
                params[groupParam] = me.encodeSorters(groupers);
            }
        }

        if (me.embeddedParams && sortParam && sorters && sorters.length > 0) {
            if (simpleSortMode) {
                index = 0;
                // Group will be included in sorters, so grab the next one
                if (sorters.length > 1 && hasGroups) {
                    index = 1;
                }
                params[sortParam] = sorters[index].property;
                params[directionParam] = sorters[index].direction;
            } else {
                params[sortParam] = me.encodeSorters(sorters);
            }

        }

        if (me.embeddedParams && filterParam && filters && filters.length > 0) {
            params[filterParam] = me.encodeFilters(filters);
        }

        return params;
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    ...
    proxy: {
        ...
        type: 'ajax', // or 'direct', 'jsonp' / 'scripttag'
        embeddedParams: false
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

add the limit property to your store...

```
  limit:50,
```

and might not hurt to try pagesize....

```
  pagesize:50
```

and see if either of these help.

Edit :  also try

```
 pageParam:undefined,
```

in your proxy.

found that last piece from...

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?118445-CLOSED-1.0.1-Ext.data.JsonStore-quot-limit-quot-param-issue

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the limit param using

```
store.proxy.limitParam=null;
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove the _dc parameter on extjs 4 you can set:

```
noCache: false
```

or just uncheck the box if you're using architect 2.

Answer (score -1):

**Specifically for Json**, to get rid of `_dc` parameter, in your proxy object, set the config option given by Tharahan:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
           read: 'app/data/something.json',
           update: 'app/data/something.json'
       },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        ...
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        ...
    },
    noCache: false
}
```

EDIT: (sorry, I did not look at the post date, but lost so much time with it) Please note that the global `Ext.Loader.setConfig({disableCaching: false});` **does not** affect subclasses of `Ext.data.proxy.Server` which need this specific option (*at least in development with sencha touch 2.2.0*).